# Angular 9: route navigation parameter problem

Tags: angular

So I want to redirect to `/user-reservations?justBooked=true` and I've tried using

```
const justBooked = 'true';
this.router.navigate(['/user-reservations', { justBooked } ]);
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['/user-reservations', { justBooked: 'true' } ]);
```

but both of those redirect to `/user-reservations;justBooked=true` which is obviously not what I want.

Why is this happening?

Comment: try `const justBooked = 'true'; this.router.navigate(['/user-reservations', justBooked ]);`

Comment: @ElasticCode it tries to redirect to `/user-reservations/true` and fails.

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['/user-reservations'], { queryParams: { justBooked: 'true' } });` it should redirect to `/user-reservations?justBooked=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.router.navigate(['/user-reservations'], { queryParams: { justBooked: 'true' } });` it should redirect to `/user-reservations?justBooked=true`

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax by the docs, you need to assign it to the `queryParams` key of the `NavigationExtras` object,
take a look at the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras).

```
this.router.navigate(['/user-reservations', { queryParams: {justBooked: 'true'} } ]);
```

Comment: What you suggest redirects to `/user-reservations;queryParams=true`.

Comment: I fixed the example

Answer (score 1):

Try use

`this.router.navigate(['/url/navigate'], { queryParams: { param1: 'value', param2: 'value2' } })`

I invite you to read the documentation at: https://angular.io/guide/router